# How to kill tmux window automatically when terminal window closed?

Tags: tmux, gnome-terminal, guake

I am starting a process in a tmux window in a terminal window. When I close the terminal window, the process not killing automatically but If I kill tmux window before close terminal window, the process killing. How can I kill related tmux window when the terminal window closed ?

Can we bind commands the close event of the terminal window ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack but you could add this to your interactive shell configuration:

```
alias tmuxn='tmux new-session -s $$'
_trap_exit() { tmux kill-session -t $$; }
trap _trap_exit EXIT
```

Then you can use `tmuxn` to start a new session. The session will be named as your shell's PID. When your shell exits, the session will be killed.

Comment: Nice hack. It does the work. I didn't know that tmux didn't close session after closing and I had like 40 sessions in my server.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can not.
For most people who use `tmux`, they usually close the terminal window instead of the tmux window in order to keep the process (`ssh-client for example`) running. And then, you can attach the origin tmux session in another terminal.
If you do not need this **feature**, you can use `terminator` instead of `tmux`.
**Terminator** splits the terminal window itself. So, if you close the terminator window, you close everything running in that window. Nothing will be kept in the background.

Comment: I love tmux. I am opening tmux windows in a terminal window for related processes(more than one tmux window) and opening another terminal window for other works. So I am working with more than one terminal window at a time. Ok, than I will kill tmux windows or detach client before close terminal window.